# Declare multiple struct fields

Tags: ida

When a struct is malloc'd, it is obvious how big that struct is. It is very tedious however to declare 64 dummy dword fields for a struct of 256 bytes. Declaring the struct to have a fixed size array doesn't help much, because you can't name the elements individually. Currently I'm using an AutoHotKey script for adding the fields, which stopped working today for whatever reason.

So: Is there a way to add multiple fields in a struct declaration at once? Maybe via some idc api?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll give you two solutions.  The first may not be exactly what you want, depending on the situation.  I can elaborate on either method if you would like.

### The cheap method: Using filler arrays

If you have a large structure and there are only a few members whose purpose or size are known, it's often useful to fill in the gaps of the structure by creating temporary dummy arrays.  This makes the structure definition more readable and maintainable in IDA, and it also allows you to shape the structure to a specific size without defining more members than you need to.

Let's say you have a structure which is known to be 0x400 bytes in size, and you know the definitions of the members at offsets +0x0 and +0x384.  Let's also say you know that there are words at +0x4 and +0x6, but you don't know what they represent yet.  Then you might define the structure to be something like this:

```
00000000 MY_STRUCT       struc ; (sizeof=0x400)
00000000 ProcessID       dd
00000004 field_4         dw
00000006 field_6         dw
00000008 __filler1       db 892 dup(?)
00000384 ProcessObject   dd ?
00000388 __filler2       db 116 dup(?)
000003FC __filler3       dd ?
00000400 MY_STRUCT       ends
```

This is much more readable than it would be if I didn't have the `__fillerX` elements there.  It's also arguably more correct, because you have no way of knowing ahead of time if all the members of the structure are actually qwords.

The reason I have `__filler3` at the bottom is because if I ever want to define an element in the region of `__filler2`, I can wipe `__filler2` (and later add new filler members in that space) without shrinking the overall size of the structure.  In fact, if the size is the only thing known at the time of structure definition, defining a final element should probably be the first thing you do.  Then you'll never need to figure out the sizes of the filler arrays yourself; the default array size that IDA gives you will always be correct.  To do that quickly, I usually just create an array of size N-4 and tack on a dword at the end.

### But I actually *want* 32 qwords!

I can't think of any practical situations where this would be useful, but maybe you can!

In any case, you can, in fact, do this through the IDA API.  The functions you want are `AddStrucEx` and `AddStrucMember`.  You should be able to get most of the information you want from the IDA help docs.

If you want a working example of an IDC script to generate structures, you can generate one yourself.  Create a few structures, then go to `File > Produce File > Dump typeinfo to IDC file...`.

Or this should also work (uses IDAPython):

```
id = AddStrucEx(-1, "EXAMPLE_STRUCT", 0)
for i in xrange(0,256,8):
    AddStrucMember(id, "field_%x"%i, i, FF_DATA|FF_QWRD, -1, 8)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll go for version 2, since I don't plan to actually use this struct for any other purposes to give names to offerts. Version 1 is a little tedious: you have to figure out the exact place to split the array and then switch to structures window to define a new field and do the splitting.

Comment: I feel a little dump that I didn't hit the API functions. Probably searched for `struct` like in `MakeStructEx` and assumed that there was no equivalent...

Comment: No problem!  I prefer the first method, but that's primarily because I often directly reference the structures subview, and I want the definitions to be readable.  I guess if you don't use that subview very often, that would be less of a issue.

Answer (score 5):

There's a neat, but unintuitive, trick for doing this in IDA which I use all the time: define an array, but in the array dialog untick the "[Create as array](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/455.shtml)" tickbox. What this does is create as many elements as you want in the struct, but doesn't make an array out of them.

The workflow is this:

- Create a single element of the type you want (e.g. a dword) at the offset where you want your list of elements. (This will often be zero when you're just creating an empty struct that you know the size of, but nothing about the internal structure).
- Press the * key with your cursor on the element you just created.
- Enter the number of elements you want in the array dialog.
- Untick the 'Create as array' tickbox in the lower left of the dialog box.
- Hit OK.

IDA will create as many elements as you asked for, but not as an array. You may need to re-type stuff later as you learn what everything is, but this gives you a good skeleton to start from.